# Why is my BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray function returning null?

Tags: java, image, android-studio, bitmap, base64

I get a base64 string representation of an image coming from a scanner I send a GET request to. On Python, I manage to convert the base64 String into an image and see it, but impossible in Java (Android Studio). I feel like I've tried everything, here is the code I use :

```
String img1_64 = datacam1.getString("image");
byte[] decodedString1 = Base64.decode(img1_64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString1, 0, decodedString1.length);
imageview1.setImageBitmap(img1);
```

The image is supposed to be 240x376.
I also tried using decodeByteArray with the option parameter, and I also tried converting an image into base64 on the internet, and using this code and it worked perfectly.
I just don't understand why it doesn't work with the scanner images.

Comment: Did you check what the value of `img1_64` is? It’s probably not what you think it should be?!

Comment: The think is when I print img1_64, I get the same thing on Python and Java, I feel like they're the same